# heroku environment variable not present in rails 4 ENV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, environment-variables, actionmailer

My ROOT_URL variable is present when executing `heroku config` but it isn't present in my ENV hash in the rails console.

All other environment variables are present. Even if I duplicate it, adding BASE_URL with the same value, one of them disappears.

```
$ heroku config
BASE_URL: my_app.herokuapp.com
ROOT_URL: my_app.herokuapp.com

$ heroku console
$ pp ENV
{"BASE_URL" => "my_app.herokuapp.com"}
```

The one that disappears is always the one I use to set :host in config.action_mailer.default_url_options.

```
# myapp/config/application.rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => ENV['ROOT_URL']}
```

Comment: Have you deployed after seting the new variable? Usually Rails need a reload to read new env variables.

Comment: Yes, I've reloaded. I've also set new variables and they're all in the heroku config list and readable from the ENV hash.